# How to run a Hadoop program?

Tags: hadoop

I have set up Hadoop on my laptop and ran the example program given in the installation guide successfully. But, I am not able to run a program.

```
rohit@renaissance1:~/hadoop/ch2$ hadoop MaxTemperature input/ncdc/sample.txt output
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MaxTemperature
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MaxTemperature
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: MaxTemperature.  Program will exit.
```

The book said that we should set a Hadoop Classpath by writing

```
rohit@renaissance1:~/hadoop/ch2$ export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=build/classes
```

The main class is defined in MaxTemperature.java file that I am executing. How do we set the Hadoop Classpath? Do we have to do it for all program execution or only once? Where should I put the input folder. My code is at /home/rohit/hadoop/ch2 and my Hadoop installation is at /home/hadoop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should package your application into a JAR file, that's much easier and less error-prone than fiddling with classpath folders.

In your case, you must also compile the .java file. You said it's MaxTemparature.java, but there must also be a MaxTemperature.class before you can run it.

Comment: The book I am referring did say that we should package the files in a jar file for easy distribution over a cluster. But, for simplicity they are using individual files at the start.

Answer (score 7):

1. First compile the Java files as told by *walid*:

   ```
   javac -classpath path-to-hadoop-0.19.2-core.jar .java-files -d folder-to-contain-classes
   ```
2. Create jar file of application classes using the following command:

   ```
   jar cf filename.jar *.class
   ```

   In either of the, whether you are exporting the classes into jar file or using specific folder to store class files , you should define `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` pointing to that particular class file or folder containing class file. So that at the time of running Hadoop command it should know where to look specified for main class.
3. set `HADOOP_CLASSPATH`

   ```
   export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=path-to-filename.jar
   ```

   or

   ```
   export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=path-to-folder-containing-classes
   ```
4. Run using Hadoop command:

   ```
   hadoop main-class args
   ```

Answer (score 6):

here is the ansewer in 3 steps:

1:

```
javac -verbose -classpath C:\\hadoop\\hadoop-0.19.2-core.jar MaxTemperature*.java -d build/classes
```

2:

```
put *.class in  build/classes
```

3:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${HADOOP_HOME}/path/to/build/classes
```

(you have to create the build/classes directory)

Best Regards
walid

Answer (score 6):

I found this problem as well when going thru the Hadoop Book (O'Reilly).  I fixed it by setting the HADOOP_CLASSPATH variable in the hadoop-env.sh file in your configuration directory.

Answer (score 2):

You do not necessarily need a jar file, but did you put MaxTemperature in a package?

If so, say your `MaxTemperature.class` file is in `yourdir/bin/yourpackage/`, all you need to do is:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=yourdir/bin
hadoop yourpackage.MaxTemperature
```

Answer (score 1):

after you make your class a jar file:

```
hadoop jar MaxTemperature.jar MaxTemperature
```

basicly :

```
hadoop jar jarfile main [args]
```