# Hadoop HDFS test running issue - org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: linux, gcc, hadoop, hdfs

I'm working with Hadoop 0.21.0. and trying to run the hdfs_test application that comes alongside the C API library. After many problems I was able to compile hdfs_test. Now when I'm running it:

```
./hdfs_test
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:153)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
... 1 more
Can't construct instance of class org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
Oops! Failed to connect to hdfs!
```

Any help is appreciated.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like any other Java program you need the dependencies in the classpath or inside the jar. Hadoop also has an HADOOP_CLASSPATH to tell the cluster where to find dependencies in map-reduce tasks. Also see [How to run a Hadoop program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799679/how-to-run-a-hadoop-program)

Comment: Thanks. It is a dependencies problem, but I wasn't able to solve it using the HADOOP_CLASSPATH. However, it turned out that I didn't really understand how CLASSPATH works. I thought that by including a folder, you will be including all jar files inside of it. My problem was solved by adding the path to the exact jar in my CLASSPATH.